# sql server query count data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

here is my Table1:

```
a   b   c
100 110 1
200 0   2
300 150 3
100 0   2
200 300 2
300 106 3
```

i want to show the result as that:

```
abc xyz
2   P
2   U
2   PL
```

this is because

count row where (b > a) as P and (b = '0') as U and (b <= a and b != '0') as PL.
problem is that how to show these value like P,U,PL these value are not exist in my Table1.
so how i am showing my table like this

```
abc xyz
 2  P
 2  U
 2  PL
```

i am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: @JohnConde SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can union the results together.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS abc ,'P' AS xyz
FROM #temp
WHERE a > b
AND b != 0
UNION
SELECT COUNT(1) AS abc, 'U' AS xyz
FROM #temp
WHERE b = 0
UNION
SELECT COUNT(1) AS abc, 'PL' AS xyz
FROM #temp
WHERE b<= a
AND b != 0
```

I had to ad b != 0 into your P condition to match your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Use a case statement

```
SELECT Count(*) as abc, CASE WHEN b= 0 THEN 'U'
    WHEN b>a THEN 'P'
    ELSE 'PL' END as xyz
FROM [Table 1]
GROUP BY
CASE WHEN a>b THEN 'P'
    WHEN b=0 THEN 'U'
    ELSE 'PL' END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as abc, symbol as xyz
from (
SELECT CASE WHEN b > a AND b != 0 THEN 'P'
    WHEN b=0 THEN 'U'
    ELSE 'PL' END as symbol
FROM [Table 1]
) as aa
group by symbol
```